# Find equivalent resistance in the circuit

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electricity, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

I think that $R_1$ and $R_2$ are in parallel and their equivalent resistance is in parallel to $R_3$.
Thus $$\frac{1}{R} = \frac{1}{(1/R_1 + 1/R_2)} + \frac{1}{R_3}$$. Please correct me if I am wrong and explain why?  [image: 1 refers to R1 and so on]

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example **type** questions. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework/exercise questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/75633) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/75633). You might want to consider posting on [some other Physics website](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/391/75633), such as the [PhysicsForums](https://www.physicsforums.com/forums/homework-and-coursework-questions.152/).

Comment: Check if your equation is dimensionally  correct .

Answer (score 1):

Your conceptual thinking is correct. Your math is not.You can confirm this by checking the units. The right side is trying to add ohms to inverse ohms (mhos). That's a signal you did something wrong.

In general, if component 1 is in parallel with component 2, and those are in parallel with component 3, then they are ALL in parallel with each other, so you could do a combination of all 3 resistors simultaneously.

Answer (score -1):

When there no electric current component between two points in the circuit then can be considered equivalent.  Like in the following case

[image]

Now you can see that there is three resistance between  A and B that are parallel.